# General Expansion formula for $(x_{1}y_{1}+x_{2}y_{2}+\cdots+x_{k-1}y_{k-1})^{2}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I am looking for a more formal way to represent the expansion of
$$
(x_{1}y_{1}+x_{2}y_{2}+\cdots+x_{k-1}y_{k-1})^{2},\quad (x_{i},y_{i})\in\mathbb{R}^{+}\times\mathbb{R}^{+}
$$
There is a nice exercise in Spivak's book on the relation
$$
(x_{1}y_{1}+x_{2}y_{2})^{2}=(x_{1}^{2}+x_{2}^{2})(y_{1}^{2}+y_{2}^{2})-(x_{1}y_{2}-x_{2}y_{1})^{2}
$$
I was wondering if we can use this to establish a general formula for $k$ variables $x_{i}$ and $y_{i}$. Any suggestion is definitely welcomed.

Comment: what is a more formal way in your definition ? Do you want this to be sum of squares?

Comment: @dezdichado That is one way for instance. Maybe we can represent it as a binomial expansion? I am not much familiar with these notations and would love to get some help with these

Comment: Hint: induction.

Comment: there are some related things that are only possible when the dimension is a power of $2.$   If you can specify something in dimension $3,$  I guess $(x_1 y_1+x_2y_2+x_3y_3)^2$  compared with $(x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2)(y_1^2 +y_2^2+y_3^2).....$  let me check

Comment: I mean this is essentially a SOS proof of Cauchy-Schwarz in the discrete settings:
$$\left(\sum x_iy_i\right)^2 = \sum_i x_i^2\sum_j y_j^2 - \sum\limits_{i<j}(x_iy_j - x_jy_i)^2$$

Comment: @SPARSE Lookup [Lagrange's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_identity).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$X = (x_1,x_2,...,x_n)$,$Y = (y_1, y_2,...,y_n)$ column vector.

Let tr(A) represent the trace of matrix $A$, it has following properties:

(1)tr(AB) = tr(BA),

(2)tr(A+B) = tr(A) + tr(B),

(3) $tr(A^T) = tr(A)$,

(4) if A is $1\times 1$ matrix then tr(A) = A.

$\sum^n_{i=1} x^2_i \sum^n_{j=1} y^2_j - (\sum^n_{i = 1} x_i y_i)^2=  X^TXY^TY - X^TYX^TY = tr(X^TXY^TY - X^TYX^TY) = tr(X^TXY^TY) - tr(X^TYX^TY) = \frac{1}{2}(tr(YX^TXY^T) + tr(XY^TYX^T) - tr(YX^TYX^T) - tr(XY^TXY^T)) = \frac{1}{2} 
(tr(YX^TXY^T + XY^TYX^T - YX^TYX^T - XY^TXY^T)) = \frac{1}{2}tr((XY^T - YX^T)^T(XY^T - YX^T)) = \sum_{i<j} (x_iy_j - y_ix_j)^2$